# How to get GXT Pallette in Eclipse Kepler?

Tags: gwt, gwt2, gxt, gwt-ext, gwt-designer

I am trying to add GXT palete in Eclipse.Using [Ext GWT (GXT)](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/tools/gwtdesigner/features/gwt/gxt)

Eclipse -Kepler

App Engine 1.9.0

GXT 2.3.1

When i right click on module file, I couldn't see this option Google Web Toolkit > Configure for using Ext GWT [image]

I also added  [Window Builder Pro](http://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/WB/integration/4.3/)

[image: Window Builder Pro]

Please help me to get the GXT palette in Eclipse. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Kepler 
There is no GWT Designer.

For the GWT Designer

New GWT Designer builds which include this patch are available from the following update sites:

http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2gwt/latest/3.6

http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2gwt/latest/3.7

http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2gwt/latest/4.2

http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2gwt/latest/4.3

**Use the 4.2 update site URL for 3.8.
For Kepler use 4.3**

Note that these are update site URLs for use with the Eclipse update manager. They are not direct download links.

**Also GWT Desinger only support 2.1.x and 2.2.5 (recommended , latest in 2.x.x series)**

After adding the pulgin and the GXT jar

Right-click on project.gwt.xml file Google Web Toolkit > Configure for using Ext GWT (GXT).  This will add the gxt.jar to your classpath and module file and various GXT files to your war folder.

Once Ext GWT (GXT) has been added to your project several new Ext GWT (GXT) palette categories will appear: